# Ruby Net::FTP storbinary writes damaged file from pipe input

Tags: ruby, ftp

I want to store a binary file using Ruby's Net::FTP class. The content for the file is put into a pipe by a previous process. I need to take the bytes from the pipe (IO class) and store it (on the fly/no temporary file) to the ftp server.

If I do it this way

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new(@@host, @@user, @@password)
ftp.debug_mode = true 
ftp.passive = true
ftp.binary = true
ftp.storbinary("STOR #{name}", pipe, Net::FTP::DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
ftp.close
```

the size of the stored file is about 500kb smaller than it should be (correct size is about 6,8 MB). The file contains gpg encrypted data. If try to decrypt, I get an error.

Storing directly from the pipe to a local file results in a file with right size and working decryption.

I'm relatively new to ruby, can someone give me a hint? Some idea for debugging? Can I provide additional informations?

Thanks for your help

---

Debug output from Net::FTP:

```
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (80,237,136,162,233,60).
put: STOR test-ftp.tar.gz.gpg
get: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for test-ftp.tar.gz.gpg
get: 226 Transfer complete
```

Ruby version: ruby 2.1.5p273

OS: debian linux

Environment: ruby script is executed directly from bash

Some more code:

```
p_out, p_in = IO.pipe
@@thread = Thread.new {
  cmd = "gpg --no-tty --cipher-algo AES256 --compress-level 0 --passphrase-file #{@@cmd.results[:gpg_passphrase_file]} --symmetric" 
  # Execute gpg
  Open3.popen3 ( cmd )  { |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|   

    Thread.new {
      cnt = IO::copy_stream pipe, stdin
      @@output.debug "GPG_Encryption::execute copied #{(Float(cnt)/1024/1024).round(2)} MiB bytes to gpg"
      pipe.close
      stdin.close
    }

    Thread.new {
      cnt = IO::copy_stream stdout, p_in
      @@output.debug "GPG_Encryption::execute copied #{(Float(cnt)/1024/1024).round(2)} MiB bytes from gpg"
    }

    # wait for gpg finished
    wait_thr.join

    # Close pipe (sends eof)
    p_in.close

    # check result
    if 0 == wait_thr.value 
      @@output.info "gpg finished..."                    
    else
      @@output.error "gpg returned an error"
      @@output.raw stderr.readlines.join
      exit 1
    end
  }
}

ftp = Net::FTP.new(@@host, @@user, @@password)
ftp.debug_mode = true 
ftp.passive = true
ftp.binary = true
ftp.storbinary("STOR #{name}", pipe, Net::FTP::DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
ftp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be closing the FTP connection before the file has been completely sent. Try removing the explicit `ftp.close`. You probably don't need it anyway as the connection will be closed automatically when `ftp` is garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks davogones, i just tried it, but it makes no difference. The stored file is still to small. But what if the whole script ends before the transfer is done? Is there a way to wait for everything sent, like join for threads?